# prompt number validation JS

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this super basic "calculator" using prompt() :

```js
var numberOne = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"))
var numberTwo = parseInt(prompt("Enter another number"))
let additionAnswer = numberOne + numberTwo
console.log("Addition answer = " + additionAnswer);
let substractionAnswer = numberOne - numberTwo
console.log("Substraction answer is " + substractionAnswer);
let multiplicationAnswer = numberOne * numberTwo
console.log("Multiplication answer = " + multiplicationAnswer);
let divisionAnswer = numberOne / numberTwo
console.log("Division answer is " + divisionAnswer);
```

Now I'm just wondering what do I do to validate that what is written in the prompts are indeed numbers.

Comment: How do you define "number"? Is 8.64e7 a number?

Comment: If there are no letters in it, it's a number.

Comment: So is "123&^%$987" a number? It doesn't have any letters. How about "1,000.00" or ".034" or …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep prompting until got the number?

```js
var numberOne = '';
var numberTwo = '';

while (isNaN(parseFloat(numberOne)) || !isFinite(numberOne)) {
  numberOne = prompt("Enter a number");
}

while (isNaN(parseFloat(numberTwo)) || !isFinite(numberTwo)) {
  numberTwo = prompt("Enter a number");
}

numberOne = parseInt(numberOne);
numberTwo = parseInt(numberTwo);

let additionAnswer = numberOne + numberTwo

console.log("Addition answer = "+ additionAnswer);

let substractionAnswer = numberOne - numberTwo 

console.log("Substraction answer is "+ substractionAnswer);

let multiplicationAnswer = numberOne * numberTwo

console.log("Multiplication answer = "+ multiplicationAnswer);

let divisionAnswer = numberOne / numberTwo

console.log("Division answer is "+ divisionAnswer);
```

Comment: Please do allow the user to not enter anything and get out of the loop

Comment: @mplungjan—that might be preferable to an endless loop. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `('/\d/').test(str1)`.

Comment: That just tests if there is a digit anywhere in the string which will allow many values that likely aren't "numbers" according to the OP.

Comment: You can adjust your regex to capture the whole string `/^\d+$/.test(str1)` which will check if the whole string is a number.
It also may be worth trimming the string prior to testing as any whitespace will return false